# How install different settings app on my xiaomi?

Tags: android, settings

My native settings app crushing when I start it, how to install the different settings application or from another shell/environment?

Answer (score 0):

You mean same package name but not same app currently installed device?

I think you should install using adb with some option.

Please try,

```
adb install -r -d [your app].apk
```

Comment: I mean is there another way to configure system and apps settings? How can I find applications from other vendors/companies?

Comment: You mean you wanna to use other setting app which is not native setting app?. There is no way. Even if you installed not native setting app, it will be crashed. This is because no other setting apps are currently configured for the platform. Only native setting app configured your current platform.